# Mongodb multi level aggregation

Tags: mongodb

Data in mongo

```
[{  
    "_id": "5d71d1432f7c8151c58c4481",
    "payment": {
        "transactions": [
            {
                "_id": "5d71d1ff2f7c8151c58c44cf",
                "method": "paytm",
                "amount": 100,
                "paymentOn": "2019-09-06T03:26:44.959Z"
            }, 
            {
                "_id": "5d71d1ff2f7c8151c58c44ce",
                "method": "cash",
                "amount": 650,
                "paymentOn": "2019-09-06T03:26:55.531Z"
            }
        ],
        "status": "partial"
    },
    "customer": "5d66c434c24f2b1fb6772014",
    "order": {
        "orderNumber": "WP-ORD-06092019-001",
        "total": 770,
        "balance": 20
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5d71d1432f7c8151c58c4481",
    "payment": {
        "transactions": [
            {
                "_id": "5d71d1ff2f7c8151c58c44cf",
                "method": "paytm",
                "amount": 100,
                "paymentOn": "2019-09-06T03:26:44.959Z"
            }
        ],
        "status": "partial"
    },
    "customer": "5d66c434c24f2b1fb6772014",
    "order": {
        "orderNumber": "WP-ORD-06092019-001",
        "total": 200,
        "balance": 100
    }
}]
```

I want to aggregate payments by method.
So the result would look like below:

```
Output:
Paytm: 200
Cash : 650
Unpaid(Balance): 120
```

I have tried:

```
[
  {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$payment.transactions', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'amount': '$payment.transactions.amount', 
      'method': '$payment.transactions.method'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$method', 
      'amount': {
        '$sum': '$amount'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But how to include balance calculation as well

Comment: What have you tried so far? Da codez, please!

Comment: Please add your code to your question by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57816575/edit).

Comment: Should not unpaid balance be 20?!

Comment: @RajivRanjan, can you please check my answer if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Using the above dataset, use the aggregate pipeline for calculation using aggregate as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      paidAmounts: [
        { '$unwind': { 'path': '$payment.transactions', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$payment.transactions.method",
            amount: {
              $sum: "$payment.transactions.amount"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      leftAmounts: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            balance: {
              $sum: "$order.balance"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

giving output:
 here leftAmounts has left balance and paidAmounts having grouped paid data on basis of payment type

```
[
  {
    "leftAmounts": [
      {
        "_id": null,
        "balance": 120
      }
    ],
    "paidAmounts": [
      {
        "_id": "cash",
        "amount": 650
      },
      {
        "_id": "paytm",
        "amount": 200
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I have to filter on order date before aggregating. So i used $match but its not giving result. 

I am using moment for date.
Following code is in node.js & mongoose as ORM.

const fromDate = moment().startOf('day');
const toDate = moment().endOf('day');

"$match": {
       "order.orderDate": { $gte: fromDate, $lte: toDate }
 }

Comment: what is format of order.orderDate in the collection? Can you try same query using
const fromDate=new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)) const toDate=new Date(new Date().setHours(23,59,59,59))

Comment: OrderDate has 2019-09-07T01:23:14.929+00:00 which is of Date type.  I tried your code but its not working.

Comment: is OrderDate's type in collection schema string or date?

Comment: OrderDate is of date type.

Comment: const fromDate = moment().startOf('day'); const toDate = moment().endOf('day'); works fine with filter but with $match aggregation its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Working solution : https://mongoplayground.net/p/7IWELKKMsWe

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$payment.transactions"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "balance": {
        "$first": "$order.balance"
      },
      "paytm": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$payment.transactions.method",
                "paytm"
              ]
            },
            "$payment.transactions.amount",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "cash": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$payment.transactions.method",
                "cash"
              ]
            },
            "$payment.transactions.amount",
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "balance": {
        "$sum": "$balance"
      },
      "cash": {
        "$sum": "$cash"
      },
      "paytm": {
        "$sum": "$paytm"
      }
    }
  }
])
```